# thmbox color bar

Tags: color, theorems, thmbox

I would like to ask if anyone knows if it is possible to change the bar color in the thmbox package. One can change the thickness of the bar but not the color.

```
\usepackage{thmbox}
\newtheorem[style=M, thickness=1pt]{theoremExa}{Example}[chapter]
\begin{document}
 \begin{theoremExa}[Example Bla]
   .....
 \end{theoremExa}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Some feedback would be kind.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following redefinition in your header. It provides a new key `color` where you can specify the color:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thmbox@color{black}
\define@key{thmbox}{color}{\def\thmbox@color{#1}}
\def\thmbox@head#1{%
  \par\noindent\vbox{%
    \setbox\thmbox@box@=\hbox{%
      \vrule width 0mm height 0mm depth \thmbox@vskip%
      #1}%
    \copy\thmbox@box@%
    \ifthmbox@underline%
       \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\hrule width \wd\thmbox@box@ height \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
    \fi}%
  \hrule height 0mm\relax}
\def\thmbox@put#1{
  \vskip\z@%
  \noindent%
  \hbox{%
    {\dimen0=\thmbox@leftmargin%
     \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@hskip%
     \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@thickness%
     \hskip\dimen0}%
    \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\vrule width \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
    \hskip\thmbox@hskip%
    \box#1%
    \ifx\thmbox@style L%
      \hskip\thmbox@hskip%
      \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\vrule width \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
    \fi}%
  \par\nobreak}
\def\thmbox@tail{%
  \hrule height 0mm%
  \ifx\thmbox@style M%
    \thmbox@dim=1cm%
  \else\ifx\thmbox@style L%
    \thmbox@dim=\hsize%
    \advance\thmbox@dim-\thmbox@leftmargin%
    \advance\thmbox@dim-\thmbox@rightmargin%
    \advance\thmbox@dim2\thmbox@hskip%
    \advance\thmbox@dim2\thmbox@thickness%
  \fi\fi%
  \noindent%
  {\dimen0=\thmbox@leftmargin%
   \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@hskip%
   \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@thickness%
   \hskip\dimen0}%
  \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\vrule width \thmbox@dim height \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
  \par}
\makeatother
```

Here a complete MWE:

> [image]

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\thmbox@color{black}
\define@key{thmbox}{color}{\def\thmbox@color{#1}}
\def\thmbox@head#1{%
  \par\noindent\vbox{%
    \setbox\thmbox@box@=\hbox{%
      \vrule width 0mm height 0mm depth \thmbox@vskip%
      #1}%
    \copy\thmbox@box@%
    \ifthmbox@underline%
       \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\hrule width \wd\thmbox@box@ height \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
    \fi}%
  \hrule height 0mm\relax}
\def\thmbox@put#1{
  \vskip\z@%
  \noindent%
  \hbox{%
    {\dimen0=\thmbox@leftmargin%
     \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@hskip%
     \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@thickness%
     \hskip\dimen0}%
    \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\vrule width \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
    \hskip\thmbox@hskip%
    \box#1%
    \ifx\thmbox@style L%
      \hskip\thmbox@hskip%
      \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\vrule width \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
    \fi}%
  \par\nobreak}
\def\thmbox@tail{%
  \hrule height 0mm%
  \ifx\thmbox@style M%
    \thmbox@dim=1cm%
  \else\ifx\thmbox@style L%
    \thmbox@dim=\hsize%
    \advance\thmbox@dim-\thmbox@leftmargin%
    \advance\thmbox@dim-\thmbox@rightmargin%
    \advance\thmbox@dim2\thmbox@hskip%
    \advance\thmbox@dim2\thmbox@thickness%
  \fi\fi%
  \noindent%
  {\dimen0=\thmbox@leftmargin%
   \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@hskip%
   \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@thickness%
   \hskip\dimen0}%
  \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\vrule width \thmbox@dim height \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
  \par}
\makeatother
\newtheorem[style=M, thickness=1pt,color=red]{theoremExa}{Example}[chapter]

\begin{document}
 \begin{theoremExa}[Example Bla]
   ......
 \end{theoremExa}
\end{document}
```