# Change line thickness in thmtools

Tags: theorems, thmtools

I am using the `thmbox=M` option with `thmtools` and I would like to change the line thickness of the box. I found how to change the colour in here: [thmbox color bar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117394/thmbox-color-bar/117397#117397). Is there an easy modification of what is in that post to apply here?!

Comment: Using the code provided in your link in the answer, you can use the following command to change both color and thickness: `\newtheorem[style=M, thickness=1pt,color=red]{theoremExa}{Example}[chapter]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [thmbox color bar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117394/thmbox-color-bar)

Comment: Thanks! I was using the `thmtools` and not `thmbox`, now I just decided to abandon `thmtools` and make my life simpler!

Comment: @LudovicC.: you might consider to turn [your comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129342/change-line-thickness-in-thmtools#comment291338_129342) into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `thmtools` does is passing on the value of the `thmbox` key as the optional argument to `thmbox`' defining command, so

```
\declaretheorem[thmbox={style=M, thickness=10pt}]{foo}
```

and you're ready to go. (Apart from the fact that 10pt would be exceedingly ugly... )

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to play with the thickness of the line, place this in your preamble:

```
\newtheorem[style=M, thickness=1pt]{theoremExa}{Example}[chapter]
```

If you also want to change the colour, you can use this piece of code provided by Marco Daniel in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117397/31058). Here is a MWE with the red colour and 2pt thickness:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\thmbox@color{black}
\define@key{thmbox}{color}{\def\thmbox@color{#1}}
\def\thmbox@head#1{%
  \par\noindent\vbox{%
    \setbox\thmbox@box@=\hbox{%
      \vrule width 0mm height 0mm depth \thmbox@vskip%
      #1}%
    \copy\thmbox@box@%
    \ifthmbox@underline%
       \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\hrule width \wd\thmbox@box@ height \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
    \fi}%
  \hrule height 0mm\relax}
\def\thmbox@put#1{
  \vskip\z@%
  \noindent%
  \hbox{%
    {\dimen0=\thmbox@leftmargin%
     \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@hskip%
     \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@thickness%
     \hskip\dimen0}%
    \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\vrule width \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
    \hskip\thmbox@hskip%
    \box#1%
    \ifx\thmbox@style L%
      \hskip\thmbox@hskip%
      \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\vrule width \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
    \fi}%
  \par\nobreak}
\def\thmbox@tail{%
  \hrule height 0mm%
  \ifx\thmbox@style M%
    \thmbox@dim=1cm%
  \else\ifx\thmbox@style L%
    \thmbox@dim=\hsize%
    \advance\thmbox@dim-\thmbox@leftmargin%
    \advance\thmbox@dim-\thmbox@rightmargin%
    \advance\thmbox@dim2\thmbox@hskip%
    \advance\thmbox@dim2\thmbox@thickness%
  \fi\fi%
  \noindent%
  {\dimen0=\thmbox@leftmargin%
   \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@hskip%
   \advance\dimen0-\thmbox@thickness%
   \hskip\dimen0}%
  \color@begingroup\color{\thmbox@color}\vrule width \thmbox@dim height \thmbox@thickness\color@endgroup%
  \par}
\makeatother

\newtheorem[style=M, thickness=2pt, color=red]{theoremExa}{Example}[chapter]
\begin{document}
 \begin{theoremExa}[Example Bla]
 Here is my customised theorem.
 \end{theoremExa}
\end{document}
```

for the following output:

[image: Output]