# Theorem style with surrounding lines

Tags: theorems

I'm using `\documentclass{book}`. I would like to create theorem styles as shown in the picture below but WITHOUT `\tcolorbox`. For some reason `\tcolorbox` doesn't work for me. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!! Here is an MWE which I use currently but doesn't look like I want I want perfectly.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,92,195}
\newenvironment{mybox}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent\arrayrulewidth=2pt\arrayrulecolor{myblue}%
   \hfill\tabularx{0.8\linewidth}{!{\color{myblue}\vrule width 2pt} X @{}}
   \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\tabular{@{}l}\kern\tabcolsep\textbf{#1}\\\hline\endtabular}\\}
  {\endtabularx\par\medskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{The title with some more text in the title}
Onyl some text here
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\begin{mybox}{The title}
\blindtext
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: @Andrew: I just did :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\def\myindent{1.5ex}
\def\rulethk{1.0pt}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,92,195}
\newenvironment{mybox}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent\arrayrulewidth=2pt\arrayrulecolor{myblue}%
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{!{\color{myblue}\hspace{\myindent}\vrule width \rulethk} X @{}}
   \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\tabular{@{}l@{}}\textbf{#1}\\\hline\endtabular}\\}
  {\\\color{myblue}\hspace{\myindent}\smash{\rule[.5pt]{10ex}{\rulethk}}\endtabularx\par\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{The title with some more text in the title}
Only some text here
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\begin{mybox}{The title}
\blindtext
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @LatexQuest You are welcome.  Most of the changes were just playing around with the `tabular` `@` parameters, an `\hspace` here or there, and rule thickness.  The trailing horizontal line was new, being added in the close-out of the environment.

Comment: @LatexQuest FYI, I made small tweaks to the solution, in reference to space above and below trailing blue line.

Comment: Thanks! Which parameters do I have to play around with to be able to adjust them?

Comment: @LatexQuest The `[.5pt]` optional argument to `\rule` moved the rule up slightly to avoid a gap forming.  If you wanted to significantly lower the rule, you would have to add a leading vertical rule to pick up where the left-rule leaves off.  As far as after the rule, I changed the `\medskip` to a `\smallskip` to better match your illustration.

Comment: @LatexQuest  If you wanted a flexible settable distance above the bottom blue line, call it `\ruleext`, then this definition would work: `\def\ruleext{1.5ex}\newenvironment{mybox}[1]{\par\medskip\noindent\arrayrulewidth=2pt\arrayrulecolor{myblue}\tabularx{\linewidth}{!{\color{myblue}\hspace{\myindent}\vrule width \rulethk} X @{}}\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\tabular{@{}l@{}}\textbf{#1}\\\hline\endtabular}\\}{\\\color{myblue}\hspace{\myindent}\smash{\rule[-\ruleext]{\rulethk}{\dimexpr\ruleext+1pt\relax}\rule[-\ruleext]{10ex}{\rulethk}}\rule[-\ruleext]{0pt}{1pt}\endtabularx\par\medskip}`

Comment: Is it possible to keep the phrase "Theorem" and Chapter no. before the title? As I show in the figure.

Comment: Could you modify your code for me?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the 'thmbox' package, a package defining a theorem environment. This makes the same "boxes" around the theorems as you'd like to have. If you'll have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117394/thmbox-color-bar/117397#117397), you'll get an extra option to change the color of the surrounding box.